# Use Data from Pickerview to change image in ARKit

Tags: swift, xcode, uipickerview, arkit

I added a `pickerview` into my app, to change placeable images for my `ARKit`(wall detection).
My first try to use 8 different `ARScenekits` was successful but i want to use 1 `Scenekit` and a `pickerview` to change the images.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var picker: UIPickerView!

var pickerData: [String] = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    // Connect data:
    self.picker.delegate = self
    self.picker.dataSource = self

    // Input the data into the array
    pickerData = ["GT2W", "GT4DW", "GT6W", "GT8W", "GT10DW", "GT12W"]
}

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// Number of columns of data
func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) ->; Int {
    return 1
}

// The number of rows of data
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) ->; Int {
    return pickerData.count
}

// The data to return fopr the row and component (column) that's being passed in
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) ->; String? {
    return pickerData[row]
}
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    // This method is triggered whenever the user makes a change to the picker selection.
    // The parameter named row and component represents what was selected.
}
```

I'm saving the selected Type in var pickerData and i want to use this var to select the right image.
[image]

After i added this function, i changed the code where the image is selected:
I changed

> material.diffuse.contents = pickerData //UIImage(named: "GT2W")

But the result is, there is only displayed a white field.
The names i used for the `pickerData` is the same as the image names.

What did i do wrong?

This is the rest of my 'placing' code:

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
guard let planeAnchor = anchor as? ARPlaneAnchor, planeAnchor.alignment == .vertical else { return }
let grid = Grid(anchor: planeAnchor)
self.grids.append(grid)
node.addChildNode(grid)
}

func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didUpdate node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
guard let planeAnchor = anchor as? ARPlaneAnchor, planeAnchor.alignment == .vertical else { return }
let grid = self.grids.filter { grid in
    return grid.anchor.identifier == planeAnchor.identifier
    }.first

guard let foundGrid = grid else {
    return
}

foundGrid.update(anchor: planeAnchor)
}

@objc func tapped(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
// Get 2D position of touch event on screen
let touchPosition = gesture.location(in: sceneView)

// Translate those 2D points to 3D points using hitTest (existing plane)
let hitTestResults = sceneView.hitTest(touchPosition, types: .existingPlaneUsingExtent)

// Get hitTest results and ensure that the hitTest corresponds to a grid that has been placed on a wall
guard let hitTest = hitTestResults.first, let anchor = hitTest.anchor as? ARPlaneAnchor, let gridIndex = grids.index(where: { $0.anchor == anchor }) else {
    return
}
addPainting(hitTest, grids[gridIndex])
}

func addPainting(_ hitResult: ARHitTestResult, _ grid: Grid) {
// 1.
let planeGeometry = SCNPlane(width: 0.1, height: 0.1)
let material = SCNMaterial()
material.diffuse.contents = pickerData //UIImage(named: "GT2W")
planeGeometry.materials = [material]

// 2.
let paintingNode = SCNNode(geometry: planeGeometry)
paintingNode.transform = SCNMatrix4(hitResult.anchor!.transform)
paintingNode.eulerAngles = SCNVector3(paintingNode.eulerAngles.x + (-Float.pi / 2), paintingNode.eulerAngles.y, paintingNode.eulerAngles.z)
paintingNode.position = SCNVector3(hitResult.worldTransform.columns.3.x, hitResult.worldTransform.columns.3.y, hitResult.worldTransform.columns.3.z)

sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(paintingNode)
grid.removeFromParentNode()
}
}
```

Comment: Do you not need to use `UIImage(named: pickerData)`?. show the actual code for the picker too, there is code missing here

Comment: I added the missing part. delegate & dataSource are linked.

Comment: Check the below, from what I can see, your not handling the selection in the picker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to need to handle selection in the picker

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, 
            didSelectRow row: Int, 
             inComponent component: Int) {

   let pickerValue = pickerData[row]
   let image = UIImage(named: pickerValue)
   // do something with the selected image
   material.diffuse.contents = image
}
```

EDIT:

Because you are getting the image within a tap gesture, we'll need a default image and we'll need to keep a reference to the last selected image. So when this first loads, if a user hasn't manually selected an image it will default to the first in the list

```
var defaultImage: UIImage {
    return UIImage(named: pickerData[0]) // just select first value
}

var selectedImage: UIImage? 

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, 
            didSelectRow row: Int, 
             inComponent component: Int) {

   let pickerValue = pickerData[row]
   selectedImage = UIImage(named: pickerValue)
}
```

Then in your current tapped function, edit the line that sets the image:

```
@objc func tapped(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
     // ... previous code 
     material.diffuse.contents = selectedImage ?? defaultImage
}
```

Comment: Sounds good after i added 'material.diffuse.contents = image' there's a warning 'Use of unresolved identifier 'material'.

Comment: thats because material isn't defined in that particular function. let me update the answer to suit your code better. give me a few mins

Comment: i tried some stuff but i still get a message 'Value of optional type 'UIImage?' must be unwrapped to a value a type 'UIImage' - at the return UIImage.

Comment: [named init](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/1624146-init) is optional as there might not be an image with that name in the project. you may need to unwrap them first. or if you are sure these images exist and will not fail you can force unwrap them using `!`

Comment: It's working with ! Thanks so much for your help... i 'love' you :D

Comment: Glad to of helped. I wouldn't normally advise ! but in this case I dont think it is too bad as you know the images are there and the options match up. good luck with the project